# add headers in api Swift / xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I have to use an api link and the website said that I have to add my key in the header

but I don t know how to add it

I tried like this but is not working :(
can someone please help?

---

```
struct PollenRequest {
 

 let resourceUrl: URL 

 let API_KEY = "123wrsgsdfhseraq24eewfesd"
    
    init(location: String){
        let resourceString = "https://api.ambeedata.com/latest/pollen/by-place?place=\(location)"
        guard let resourceUrl = URL(string: resourceString) else { fatalError() }
        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: resourceString)! as URL)
        request.addValue("123wrsgsdfhseraq24eewfesd",forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
        
        self.resourceUrl = resourceUrl
    }
    
    func getPollen (completion: @escaping(Result<[PollenData], PollenError>) -> Void){
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resourceUrl){data, _, _ in
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let pollenResponse = try decoder.decode(PollenResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                let pollenDetails = pollenResponse.data
                completion(.success(pollenDetails))
                
            }catch{
                completion(.failure(.notProcessedData))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the easiest approach is to get the request working in Postman and then ask Postman just to generate the Swift code for you!

Answer (score 3):

Rather than saving the `URL` you have to save the `URLRequest`

And don't use `NS..` types if there is a native Swift equivalent

```
struct PollenRequest {

 let urlRequest: URLRequest

 let API_KEY = "123wrsgsdfhseraq24eewfesd"
    
    init(location: String) {
        let resourceString = "https://api.ambeedata.com/latest/pollen/by-place?place=\(location)"
        guard let resourceUrl = URL(string: resourceString) else { fatalError() }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: resourceUrl)
        request.addValue(API_KEY, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-api-key")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
        self.urlRequest = request
    }
    
    func getPollen (completion: @escaping(Result<[PollenData], PollenError>) -> Void){
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {data, _, _ in
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                completion(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let pollenResponse = try decoder.decode(PollenResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                let pollenDetails = pollenResponse.data
                completion(.success(pollenDetails))
                
            }catch{
                completion(.failure(.notProcessedData))
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Side note:

In case of an error returning `.notProcessedData` is meaningless. You should return the **real** `DecodingError`